# php: i have 5 array, how can i make them as one?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

```
    foreach($archive as $archrow){
        echo $archrow->doc_name;   //document name
        echo $archrow->doc_status; //document status
    }

    foreach($arc as $arcrow){
        echo $arcrow->fullname; //Author
    }

    foreach($pos as $posrow){
        echo $posrow->position_name;  //position

    }

    foreach($loc as $locrow){

        echo $locrow->location;  //Department
    }
```

i would like to make a table and arrange them by category like this:

```
________________________________________________________________________________
```

|Document name |  Author   |   Position   |  Department  |   Document Status     |

---

|  asdasd      |  john     |    Manager   |  Acct        |    adsads             |

Comment: How do you get the data into these five arrays in the first place? It might be easier getting the structure you want at that point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to assume you want extract one element form each array at the same time

You can try

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator(MIT_NEED_ANY|MIT_KEYS_NUMERIC);
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($archive), 'achive');
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($arc), 'arc');
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($pos), 'pos');
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($loc), 'loc');

echo "<pre>";
foreach ( $mi as $member ) {
    echo $member['achive']->doc_name, "|", $member['achive']->doc_status, "|", $member['arc']->fullname, "|", $member['pos']->position_name, "|", $member['loc']->position_name ,PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: i have an error with this part MultipleIterator(MIT_NEED_ANY|MIT_KEYS_NUMERIC).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge arrays you can use `array_merge`for that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php
But your example isn't an array...